# MySQL convert every date field to timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I developed a hybrid app with sencha touch 2 and mysql.
The problem is that I made a big mistake. I saved all date fields in this format as varchar:

```
'23.05.2013 19:00'
```

And now its quite complicated to sort this field. I now would like to convert every field as timestamp.

Can I do this with a mysql query?

Or do I have to read every record with PHP, change the value and update the field?

Comment: The `datetime` data time uses internal storage.  Don't confuse this with the presentation of the `datetime`.  You can just use `order by datetimecol` for sorting.  You most emphatically did not make a mistake.

Comment: Looks to me like you made a big mistake! That's NOT datetime format.

Comment: There's no one liner that can help you alter the storage type of the column and import the data properly. What you can do is create another column (temporary) that holds the `datetime`, and run a query that reads each varchar column, formats it and populates the temporary datetime column. After that it's just a matter of changing the bad column from varchar to datetime and populating it with values from temp column that you can drop afterwards. It's a matter of 3 queries and you can do it from terminal.

Comment: You are right... the seconds are missing. Thats maybe also the problem why I can´t sort this field.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we want to convert '23.05.2013 19:01' to '2013-05-23 19:01:00', we can do with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` and `MAKEDATE()`.

```
SET @dt := '23.05.2013 19:01';

SELECT @dt, SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dt, '.', 1) AS day,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dt, '.', 2), '.', -1) AS month,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dt, '.', 3), '.', -1), ' ', 1) AS year,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dt, ' ', -1), ':', 1) AS hour,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dt, ' ', -1), ':', 2), ':', -1) AS minute,
  '00' AS second;
+------------------+------+-------+------+------+--------+--------+
| @dt              | day  | month | year | hour | minute | second |
+------------------+------+-------+------+------+--------+--------+
| 23.05.2013 19:01 | 23   | 05    | 2013 | 19   | 01     | 00     |
+------------------+------+-------+------+------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT @dt, CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dt, '.', 3), '.', -1), ' ', 1), '-',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dt, '.', 2), '.', -1), '-',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dt, '.', 1), ' ',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dt, ' ', -1), ':', 1), ':',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dt, ' ', -1), ':', 2), ':', -1), ':00') AS datetime;
+------------------+---------------------+
| @dt              | datetime            |
+------------------+---------------------+
| 23.05.2013 19:01 | 2013-05-23 19:01:00 |
+------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally, we need following SQLs;

```
// add temp column
ALTER TABLE tab ADD valid_datetime DATETIME;

// update temp column to valid datetime value
UPDATE tab SET valid_datetime = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(wrong_datetime, '.', 3), '.', -1), ' ', 1), '-',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(wrong_datetime, '.', 2), '.', -1), '-',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(wrong_datetime, '.', 1), ' ',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(wrong_datetime, ' ', -1), ':', 1), ':',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(wrong_datetime, ' ', -1), ':', 2), ':', -1), ':00');

// rename temp column to old column
ALTER TABLE tab DROP wrong_datetime, CHANGE valid_datetime wrong_datetime DATETIME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints guys!

I managed it now to sort the table without converting it to timestamp:

```
SELECT datefield FROM mytable ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(datefield, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') DESC
```

Now I can sort the table or convert it to timestamp as N.B. suggested.